# I am getting ModelState error "The id field is required." But Id field is already entered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelstate

This razor Page Create new **Continent** and if an **ID** is passed in **OnGetAsync** method

This EditContinent.cshtml.cs will just edit the given id continent.
Below is the Model, in its ***OnPost*** method is showing error only when i try to ***Add*** new continent.

It is updating just fine which is in the ***else*** statement.

This error is showing

**{The id field is required.}**

I am using sqlite database

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using World.Data;
using World.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace World.Pages
{
    public class EditContinentModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ContinentContext _context;
        
        public EditContinentModel(ContinentContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Continent Continent { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                Continent = new Continent();
            }
            else
            {
                Continent = await _context.Continents.FindAsync(id);

                if (Continent == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
            }
            return Page();
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ModelState is not Valid");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v=>v.Errors));
                return Page();
            }
            if (id == null)
            {
               await _context.Continents.AddAsync(Continent);
            }
            else
            {
                _context.Attach(Continent).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

This the razor page for the model above

```
    @page "{id?}"
    @model World.Pages.EditContinentModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Continent";
    }
    <div class="parentDiv">
        <div class="header1">
        <h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
    </div>
    <form method="post" class="formEdit">
        <div class="flex_row">
            <label asp-for="Continent.ID">ID</label>
            <input  asp-for="Continent.ID" type="text" required/>
           
        </div>
        <div class="flex_row">
            <label asp-for="Continent.Name">Name</label>
            <input  asp-for="Continent.Name" type="text" required/>
            
        </div>
        <div class="savebutton">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This below is my model for the **DbSet**

```
    namespace World.Models
    {
        public class Continent
        {
            
            public string ID { get; set; }
          
            public string Name { get; set; }
            
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not an error.... it seems like you're calling `.ToString()` somewhere on an object that you shouldn't be. That's presumably the line `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v=>v.Errors));`, because you're trying to call `.ToString` on the result of `SelectMany` rather than the individual errors themselves.

Comment: Situation was still the same even before i added the **System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v=>v.Errors));**

Comment: _"The error started showing after I added the statement"_ - again: that is NOT an error.

Comment: Perhaps try printing the actual errors, rather than the result of `SelectMany`'s result's `.ToString` method?: `foreach (var error in ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v=>v.Errors)) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage); }`?

Comment: It is showing **"The id field is required."** But i have entered the Id field in the input

Comment: Is it perhaps referring to **id** in **Onget** method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed  `public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string id)` to

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string? id)
```

Same goes in post and it worked.